# How to extract all coefficients in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

You can get a coefficient of a specific term by using coeff();

```
x, a = symbols("x, a")
expr = 3 + x + x**2 + a*x*2
expr.coeff(x)
# 2*a + 1
```

Here I want to extract all the coefficients of x, x**2 (and so on), like;

```
# for example
expr.coefficients(x)
# want {1: 3, x: (2*a + 1), x**2: 1}
```

There is a method as_coefficients_dict(), but it seems this doesn't work in the way I want;

```
expr.as_coefficients_dict()
# {1: 3, x: 1, x**2: 1, a*x: 2}
expr.collect(x).as_coefficients_dict()
# {1: 3, x**2: 1, x*(2*a + 1): 1}
```

Comment: Are there limits on your expression `expr`, i.e. is it always a polynomial? Is its degree limited?

Comment: @Carsten It would be great if there's an "unlimited" way, and in fact I think there must be especially because collect() is (probably) unlimited, but at least a method that works on a polynomial is needed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Poly`

```
>>> a = Poly(expr, x)
>>> a.coeffs()
[1, 2*a + 1, 3]
```

Comment: Note that this hides zeros. If you do `Poly(x**2 + 1).coeffs()` you get `[1,1]` and not `[1,0,1]`.

Answer (score 67):

`all_coeffs()` can be sometime better than using `coeffs()` for a `Poly`.
The difference lies in output of these both. `coeffs()` returns a list containing all coefficients which has a value and ignores those whose coefficient is `0` whereas `all_coeffs()` returns all coefficients including those whose coefficient is zero.

```
>>> a = Poly(x**3 + a*x**2 - b, x)
>>> a.coeffs()
[1, a, -b]

>>> a.all_coeffs()
[1, a, 0, -b]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was caught with my pants down by `coeffs()` ignoring zeroed coefficients. It's also worth noting that `numpy` uses the reverse ordering so  when using `numpy` polynomial its worthwhile doing `a.reverse()`

Comment: Can I just ask, what's going on when you write `a = Poly(x**3 + a*x**2 - b, x)`? It looks like you're entering an equation with `a` on both sides, but I guess that's not what you're doing since SymPy doesn't know that you're assigning the polynomial to a variable that also has the name "`a`". But did you choose that name for some specific reason, instead of calling it for example "`p`", for polynomial? Otherwise, I find it a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Collection of coefficients can be handled with Poly and then separation of the monomials into dependent and independent parts can be handled with `Expr.as_independent`:

```
def codict(expr, *x):
  collected = Poly(expr, *x).as_expr()
  i, d = collected.as_independent(*x, as_Add=True)
  rv = dict(i.as_independent(*x, as_Mul=True)[::-1] for i in Add.make_args(d))
  if i:
      assert 1 not in rv
      rv.update({S.One: i})
  return rv

>>> var('a x z y')
(a, x, z, y)
>>> expr = 3 + x + x**2 + a*x*2
>>> codict(expr, x)
{x**2: 1, x: 2*a + 1, 1: 3}
>>> codict(expr+y+z, x)
{x**2: 1, x: 2*a + 1, 1: y + z + 3}
>>> codict(expr+y+z, x,y)
{y: 1, x**2: 1, x: 2*a + 1, 1: z + 3}
>>> codict(expr+y+z, x,y,z)
{y: 1, z: 1, x**2: 1, x: 2*a + 1, 1: 3}
```

Comment: This does not work. Sometimes there are more than one entry in the dict for 1, in which case only the last is stored. You need to sum over all entries with same key in the dict.

Comment: Thanks. The code and example has been updated.

Comment: Simply outstanding.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is use a dictionary comprehension like so:

```
dict = {x**p: expr.collect(x).coeff(x**p) for p in range(1,n)}
```

where n is the highest power+1. In this case n=3. So you would have the list `[1,2]`

This would give

```
dict = {x: (2*a+1), x**2: 1}
```

Then you can add in the single term with

```
dict[1] = 3
```

So

```
 dict = {1:3,x:(2*a+1),x**2:1}
```

You may also try:

```
a = list(reversed(expr.collect(x).as_ordered_terms()))
dict = {x**p: a[p],coeff(x**p) for p in range(1,n)}
dict[1] = a[0] # Would only apply if there is single term such as the 3 in the example
```

where n is the highest power + 1.

Comment: As an exception, this works on series() while Poly() doesn't. ■ Side note, you can also write `.coeff(x, p)` which would allow `p=0` (constant term).

Answer (score 0):

Based on RDizzl3's answer, I modified like this:

```py
d_c = collect(my_poly, x)
# replace n by highest power + 1 
dict = {x**p: d_c.coeff(x, p) for p in range(0,n)}
```

This does not skip the constant.