# Calculating the coefficients of a differentiated polynomial using re.compile and searching in python

Tags: python, regex, polynomials, differentiation

Testing the polynomial '*2x^3+4x^2+8x-16*' my code below outputs *[6, 8]* as the coefficients of the differentiated polynomial. However, the output should be *[6, 8, 8]*. **Why is the function getNewCoefficients producing the wrong result? What would be a good way to produce the correct result?**

```
def getNumbers(polynomial):
    regex = re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?")
    return  regex.findall(polynomial)

def formatNumbers(numbers):
    formattedNumbers = []
    for e in numbers:
        if (e[0] == '+'):
            formattedNumbers.append(e[1:])
        else:
            formattedNumbers.append(e)
    return formattedNumbers

def getNumberPositions(polynomial, numbers):
    numberPositions =  []
    for e in numbers:
        tmp = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(e, polynomial)]  
        for f in tmp:
           if f not in numberPositions:
                numberPositions.append(f)
    return sorted(numberPositions)

def getNewCoefficients(polynomial, numberPositions, numbers):
    tmp = '0'
    newCoefficients = []
    for i in range(0,len(numberPositions)):
        if numberPositions[i] + 1 < len(polynomial):
            if polynomial[numberPositions[i] + 1] == '+' or polynomial[numberPositions[i] + 1] == '-':
                newCoefficients.append(int(numbers[i])*int(tmp))
        elif numberPositions[i] - 1 > 0:
            if polynomial[numberPositions[i] - 1] == '+' or polynomial[numberPositions[i] - 1] == '-':
                newCoefficients.append(int(numbers[i]))
        tmp = numbers[i]
    return newCoefficients
```

Comment: Looks like a math question. Fwiw, I don't see `getNumbers` being called where that contains the only regex I see. Also, this text `2x^3+4x^2+8x-16` is not in a suitable form to represent an equation to a computer algorithm.

Comment: Seems to me that if you use that regex to get the numbers, and then depend on the resulting array that you'll get `['2', '3', '4', '2', '8', '-16']`.  Wouldn't that represent `2x^3+4x^2+8x^-16` ?

Comment: Does it account for if there is no explicit exponent, like `+8x` (since that's the part that's missing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved much more easily using negative lookbehind assertions.

```
COEFFICIENT_PATTERN = re.compile(r"(?<!x\^)(?<!x\^-)-?\d+")
coefficients = [int(c) for c in COEFFICIENT_PATTERN.findall(polynomial)]
```

This solution uses two negative lookbehinds for `x^` and `x^-` (because look behinds must be fixed length). So it reads "get me all integers not preceded by `x^`.

```
>>> COEFFICIENT_PATTERN.findall('2x^3+4x^2+8x-16')
['2', '4', '8', '-16']
```

Comment: Thanks @sln I had the `\\` in my repl and forgot it in the example :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `re` module, you can use the `sympy` module, but you have to download it first from http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html. I'm not a `sympy` expert, but I found a similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955888/how-to-extract-all-coefficients-in-sympy) that may help you.

And, just to let you know, exponents does not count as coefficients...

Comment: Sympy is great, but it's also a fairly large dependency. It may be overkill if you're doing something simple.