# Polynomial multiplication in python

Tags: python-3.x, polynomials

I need to find product of two polynomials.

Input:

```
x+2; x^3-x^2+1
```

Output:

`x^4+x^3-2x^2+x+2`

I have two questions:

1) How to extract coeff. from polynomials.

2) How to build new polynomial using new coeff. (output form in example)

I'm not allowed to use additional libraries.

Comment: you can use sympy library for that.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use additional libraries, but i would be happy if you can give me an example of code to solve this problem using libraries

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far and what is failing in your current implementation?

Comment: @ParvBanks i know how to solve this problem if input consists only of coeff. like [1,2] and [1,-1,1] but i dont know how to work with polynomials in python in their natural form, like in my example

Comment: Have you tried using `regex` to identify the coefficients? Once you have those, you can use your current solution to solve. It will also not need additional libraries (except `re`)

Comment: @ParvBanks i will read documentation, because i've dealt with regex. Hope it will help. thank you

Comment: **You could use `regex` to identify the polynomials from your expressions.** I found a similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914959/calculating-the-coefficients-of-a-differentiated-polynomial-using-re-compile-and). Please check if it works for you. **The result is a list of coefficients which is what you're looking to integrate with your solution.**

Comment: I have found a possible solution, you can check my answer.

Comment: @friendly_user Please [edit] the question to mention that you can't use additional libraries, plus any other specific requirements. Also add anything you've tried so far and the results.