# How to get coefficients in sympy expression/ Python

Tags: python, sympy, coefficients

How to get coefficients in sympy expression

```
b = sympy.Symbol('b')
a = sympy.Symbol('a')
x = sympy.Symbol('x')

y = 2*x**3 + a*x**2 +b*x
```

The result should be :

`coeff for x**3 =2
coeff for x**2 = a
coeff for x = b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract all coefficients in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955888/how-to-extract-all-coefficients-in-sympy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprisingly awkward to get the expression form of the terms in the polynomial but you can do it like this:

```
In [28]: b = sympy.Symbol('b') 
    ...: a = sympy.Symbol('a') 
    ...: x = sympy.Symbol('x') 
    ...:  
    ...: y = 2*x**3 + a*x**2 +b*x

In [29]: p = Poly(y, x)

In [30]: p
Out[30]: Poly(2*x**3 + a*x**2 + b*x, x, domain='ZZ[a,b]')

In [31]: {x**m[0]:p.coeff_monomial(m) for m in p.monoms()}
Out[31]: 
⎧       2      3   ⎫
⎨x: b, x : a, x : 2⎬
⎩                  ⎭
```

Answer (score 1):

Although getting the coefficients is easy

```
>>> y = 2*x**3 + a*x**2 + b
>>> p = Poly(y, x)
>>> p.coeffs()
[2, a, b]
>>> p.all_coeffs()
[2, a, 0, b]
```

getting them linked up to their monomial is the unimplemented/ackward part. @OscarBenjamin showed how to do this with the monomials of the Poly. You can also work with the expression without converting it to a Poly:

```
>>> dict(i.as_independent(x)[::-1] for i in Add.make_args(y))
{1: b, x**3: 2, x**2: a}
```

It would be a nice "battery" for SymPy to include a `mapping` keyword on `Poly.coeffs` that would allow this dictionary to be returned. Alternatively, `Expr.as_coefficients_dict` could be given an optional `variable` keyword that would allow the coefficients to be returned which are indepenedent of any symbols in `variable`.

This simple dict-comprehension will fail if there are uncollected terms like `a*x + b*x` in the expression. A more robust little function is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552819/1089161).