# How to get a list of coefficients of an expression in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

Lets say I have an expression like this in SymPy:

```py
s = sp.symbols('s')
Y = s**3 + 3*s**2 + 2*s
Y
```

[image]

Now I would like to get a "list of orders" of that expression.
here is an example of what I want to achieve:
I would like to create a `tf()` object. Where `tf()` is a function like in Matlab that takes two lists, a denominator, and a numerator, and creates a transfer function out of them:

```py
tf([1], [1, 3, 2, 0])
```

I would like to extract those two lists from my SymPy expression to use them like in that `tf()` function. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24127329)?

Comment: `sp.Poly(s**3 + 3*s**2 + 2*s, s).all_coeffs()` does the job! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After transforming an expression into a polynomial `all_coeffs()` does the job:

```py
sp.Poly(s**3 + 3*s**2 + 2*s, s).all_coeffs()
```

```
[1, 3, 2, 0]
```