# "as_coefficients_dict() not found" error in Julia 1.7.1

Tags: python, julia, sympy

I am trying to use `as_coefficients_dict` (a python) function in Julia 1.7.1 but getting the error below:

[image]

The error occurs in the below code in the last line where I have
`S = [p0].as_coefficients_dict().keys()`. See the code below:

```
p0 = sympify(dense_interpolation([a[1]] .+ r, [p0] .+ P).subs(Symbol('x'), x_var[1]))
S = [p0].as_coefficients_dict().keys()
```

`as_coefficients_dict()` is a python function. How to represent it in Julia? 
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Likely you need to make your object a Poly instance first.

Comment: i tried it, didn't work, the problem is : can we represent the as_coefficients_dict() in julia, if there is any way, it would be great if you mention it :)

Comment: I’m not at my computer, so can’t get you a working example, but using coeffs(ex, var) form to pull out the coefficient of the monomial var could be used.  An example in python that could be modified is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955888/how-to-extract-all-coefficients-in-sympy

Comment: It is unclear to me why you are calling `[p0].as_coefficients_dict` as opposed to `p0.as_coefficients_dict`; if this is Julia syntax, then this would appear to be wrapping `p0` in an array, which could not possibly have `as_coefficients_dict` as a field